# Set a keyboard shortcut using two letters or more?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04

For mnemonic reasons, I would like to create keyboard shortcuts for custom scripts on my Ubuntu 22.04 using Gnome on XOrg with more than a single letter in the shortcut. For example, I might like to assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to launch `apple_blossom.sh`

However, when I attempt to assign such a shortcut using Add Custom Shortcut in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Add Custom Shortcut > Set Shortcut… only a single character is recognized (e.g., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

**Is there a solution to assigning two-letter shortcuts on my system?**

**Edit:** I am aware that one may assign multiple modifier keys in a straightforward fashion (e.g., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). (And also that modifer keys can come in 'left' and 'right' flavors. :) This is a question specifically about two letter keys.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any tool that can trigger commands based on shortcut combinations consisting out of more than one regular key. While you can have multiple modifier keys (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>), typically, you only can have a single regular key.

Slightly different than what you are looking for, the tool `sxhkd` allows for "chords chains", e.g. where you press for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by another key, e.g. <kbd>B</kbd>. However, it only works on Xorg.

Comment: I will look into `sxhkd`, as it sounds like quite close to a solution, thank you!